# Banner with autoheighted edges (absolute position)

Tags: html, css

Well, this is somewhat I want:

```
<body style="background-color: green;">
<div style="float: left; height: 40px; width: 50%; background-color: white;"></div>
<div style="float: left; height: 40px; width: 50%; background-color: black;"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
    <div style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: dotted yellow 1px; background-color: green;">
        <img src="http://prog.hu/site/images/logo.gif" width="100%" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g4EEc/2/

this does what I want, only thing is the height of the edges must be dynamic, as height as the banner is. Is there a solution?

Comment: can't understand what you want to achieve? let me know

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Please clarify what the problem is and what you want to achieve. Which 'edges' are you referring too

Comment: Please be specific what you want to know.

Comment: sorry. I meant the "white" and "black" "edges", I made it as they were edges, because logo will hide them. I didnt want to put 2 divs at left and right next to banner, its easier to do as background

Comment: so I want the white and black divs as height as the img does. Without setting the height manually, and the banner can shrink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g4EEc/3/

code

```
<body style="background-color: green;">
<div style="overflow:hidden;background:#ccc;position:relative;z-index:34">
    <div style="height:1000px;width:50%;background:#fff;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:-2"></div>
    <div style="height:1000px;width:50%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;z-index:-2"></div>
    <img src="http://prog.hu/site/images/logo.gif" style=" border: dotted yellow 1px; background-color: green;display:block;margin:0 auto;z-index:34;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML looks a bit scary. Try to put the whole in a wrapper and scale  by wrapper. To achieve the two colors I used a css3 gradient here.

```
<div class="outerwrapper">    
 <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://prog.hu/site/images/logo.gif" width="100%" />
 </div>
</div><!-- outer wrapper -->
```

and the css:

```
.outerwrapper{
    height:15%;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0%,#fff 50%,#000 51%,#000 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff 0%,#fff 50%,#000 51%,#000 100%); 
}
.wrapper{
    display:block;
    background: green;
    width: 33%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.left{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.right{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w639Z/

I also would really recommend you not to write styles inline, instead of using seperate css.